# How to use Angular variable in expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<div ng:repeat='row in _.range(0,{{rowCount}})'></div>
```

but it doesn't evaluate `{{rowCount}}`. What do I need to do to get it to evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ngRepeat already evals the expression you pass it. You don't need - and really shouldn't -  use {{}}. Just reference rowCount:

```
<div ng:repeat='row in _.range(0,rowCount)'></div>
```

And it should work!